# Setting controller, action, and values based on the number of URL chunks

Tags: php, url-routing

Is there any way to improve this code? It looks a bit ugly for me.

```
if($url_chunks_num == 1) {
    $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
} elseif($url_chunks_num == 2) {
    $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
    $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
} elseif($url_chunks_num > 2) {
    $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
    $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
    $this->values = array_slice($this->pageData, 2);
}
```

I thought about nested conditions, but this option is ugly as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with luiscubal about restructuring the code (with the one minor difference that I would use braces), however, I think you could make something a bit cleaner with [array_shift](https://www.php.net/array_shift).

```
$this->controller = array_shift($this->pageData);
$this->action = array_shift($this->pageData);
$this->values = $this->pageData;
```

This is functionally equivalent to the code luiscubal posted, though his does not define defaults.  (The two strings would default to `NULL` and then `$this->values` would default to `array()`.)

This does change $this->pageData though, so if you need to keep that data around (which is implied by it being a property), you'll need to either use luiscubal's approach or create a temporary copy.

---

Since the array is small, and PHP is typically copy-on-write, making a copy shouldn't be an issue, however, if you're worried, you could take a non-direct route to basically have the same amount of copying as the if trees have:

```
$this->values = $this->pageData;
$this->controller = array_shift($this->values);
$this->action = array_shift($this->values);
```

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be some code repetition. Perhaps this could be improved like this:

```
if ($url_chunks_num >= 1)
   $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
if ($url_chunks_num >= 2)
   $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
if ($url_chunks_num > 2)
   $this->values = array_slice($his->pageData, 2);
```

Or

```
if ($url_chunks_num >= 1) {
   $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
   if ($url_chunks_num >= 2)
      $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
   if ($url_chunks_num > 2)
      $this->values = array_slice($his->pageData, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this should look better.

```
if ($url_chunks_num>0)
    $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
if($url_chunks_num > 1)
    $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
if($url_chunks_num > 2) {
    $this->values = array_slice($this->pageData, 2);
```

but also using a switch statement should be nicer... i do not know if it works, should be tested...

```
switch ($url_chunks_num) {
    default:
        $this->values = array_slice($this->pageData, 2);
    case 2:
        $this->action = $this->pageData[1];
    case 1:
        $this->controller = $this->pageData[0];
    case 0:
        break;
}
```

as you do not use breaks in cases it shold work like it is in your structure.

last exit before bridge : you should test it esp. for syntax errors.

Comment: The switch syntax is correct, as is the logic (I believe).  I must say though, I always avoid switch statements that fall through, and the way `default` is structured irks me a little.  Definitely creative though!  +1

Comment: well using if's in this piece of code is just bad in terms of optimization... and yes i know this is just some web application, and yes i am obsessive ;)

Comment: I would be surprised if there's even a 1 us difference (probably even less than that).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it just how Corbin suggested, but the above is still valid. You could also check out `list()` and, if `$pageData` were associative with keys of the same title you could use variable variables. Disclaimer: I do not advise the use of variable variables, merely pointing it out for completeness.

Comment: this would behave differently from the original code, for example if `$url_chunks_num == 0`. In your code the line `$this->controller = $this->pageData[0];` will be executed, while in the original it will not.

Comment: @nadirs: You are quite right, can't believe I missed that. I'll remove the code snippet, as I can't make that look any better with the added constraint. However, I'll leave the answer up for the rest is still relevant.

Comment: List requires you to know that the elements exist. And variable variables would have the same problem. -1 isn't me though.

Comment: Its actually -2. However, the issue with list can be fixed by checking its length and appending elements onto it so that it has the right default amount, even if those are empty. I'll probably just end up deleting this post as it appears that it is not going over well -.-